# OSX - can't find what's adding python to my path

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, path-variables

I've just upgraded to OSX Yosemite. I'm running `brew doctor` and among the zillions of warnings it generates is:

```
Warning: /usr/local/share/python is not needed in PATH.
Formerly homebrew put Python scripts you installed via `pip` or `pip3`
(or `easy_install`) into that directory above but now it can be removed
from your PATH variable.
Python scripts will now install into /usr/local/bin.
You can delete anything, except 'Extras', from the /usr/local/share/python
(and /usr/local/share/python3) dir and install affected Python packages
anew with `pip install --upgrade`.
```

I've looked carefully everywhere, and I can't find what is adding /usr/local/share/python to my path. My .bash_profile contains no mention of python. /private/etc/paths.d contains only a file called "git". I did find an instance of /usr/local/share/python in /private/etc/paths, but I deleted that, but when I start a new terminal after that and rerun `brew doctor` I still get the warning. Can anyone suggest how I can stop this? It's driving me insane!

Comment: ...and people still ask me why I prefer macports over brew (no issues for me after Yosemite upgrade) :P

Comment: If you haven't upgraded brew in a while, this could be a symptom of that (it even states so in the error message). Previously brew used `/usr/local/share/python`. FWIW I faced no such warnings on my upgrade (but this could be because I am very protective of my PATH).

Answer (score 0):

Im not able to comment, and while I don't have an answer, this might help through process of elimination, or potentially help your future problem solver.

- What about `etc/profile`; any sign in that file?
- Do you have a `~/.profile` it could be in?
- What do you get when you: `echo $PATH`, any sign of said path?
- What about `export`, or `declare` (with no options)?
- How are you setting/exporting your desired path now?

Probably not what you want to hear, but I always do a fresh install rather than upgrade for fear of issues like this. Doing so would most likely solve your issues; all zillion of them. I know I haven't had any issues, or even a single warning from Homebrew, since I moved to Yosemite.